# Could I use a SSRS report to link to network files that a user cannot access directly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

*This is on sql server 2008r2*

I am trying to figuire out if it is possible to use a SSRS report to show the user a unique list of network files they can see, as defined by a permissions table, so they can open them without giving them explicit network permission to directly access them.

The basic setup would be something like:

- There is a network folder (“repository”) that contains all the files
- Only the service account has permission to this folder
- There is a table on the server that defines who can see what files by username
- Through a SSRS report, the user is shown a list of the files he can
  view
- This list contains hyperlinks to all files

Desired outcome:

- User clicks the file, the service account “retrieves” the file through an implicit procedure not exposed to the user
- User tries to copy/open a hyperlink in explorer results in a not found error

Edit: I want the user to be able to open the file through the hyperlink in the report.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do that, or you could just grant them a "list directory" privilege on the folder in question, but not "read".